# 5 star ratings. Bayesian or Weighted average?

Tags: average

I am building a website which has 5 star ratings to rate items.

These ratings unlike the normal ones are of unequal weights. i.e.

```
1 star: -5,
2 stars: 10,
3 stars: 20,
4 stars: 30,
5 stars: 50,
```

Every time a user rates I am planning to calculate the average and show it back to the user.

To do this averaging I was thinking of implementing [weighted averages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_mean) or [Bayesian average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_average).

Which approach do you think is the best? Are there other approaches I should be looking into?

Comment: Here's another approach you could look into: [How Not To Sort By Average Rating](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) by Evan Miller

Comment: Questions like this don't have an objective answer. It all depends on what you want your rating system to do.

Comment: @Rahul Evan's post is specifically for rating systems without a limit. i.e. a voting system

Answer (score 15):

The basic (weighted) average is really just a special case of the Bayesian average with $C = 0$.  There are other special cases, such as the [rule of succession](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession), which correspond to different priors.  More generally, these are all forms of [additive smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing).

Generally, I'd suggest either implementing *some* form of smoothing and/or not showing any ratings for items rated less than some minimum number of times.  This is to avoid the issue of an item with a single 5-star rating getting a higher average rating than one with 99 5-star ratings and one 4-star rating.

Ps. If you haven't yet seen [yesterday's xkcd strip](http://www.xkcd.com/937/), go take a look at it — it's relevant to the topic.