# Calculating a 5 star rating with a reputation number...

Tags: average

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [5 star ratings. Bayesian or Weighted average?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57849/5-star-ratings-bayesian-or-weighted-average)

[Similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57849/5-star-ratings-bayesian-or-weighted-average), but unlike that question this deals with two factors the stars and reputation.

Lets say Stack Exchange were to have a 5 star rating system instead of up vote and down vote.

- 1 star = 5 reputation
- 2 stars = -2 reputation
- 3 stars = 0 reputation
- 4 stars = +2 reputation
- 5 stars = +5 reputation

So far so good, as it is very easy to calculate the total reputation (just by adding).

But what if each user had a 5 star rate, instead of reputation number? How could we calculate the stars?

Comment: Why downvote? At least be usefull and explain...

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. I have several guesses, but 1) I shouldn't have to guess and 2) they are all covered by the linked question as far as I can tell. What is wrong with assigning a score out of 5 as per the linked question?

Comment: Allright then, if somebody could delete this question, seeing by the negative vote, this is not worth it...

Comment: @JoshDruve I flagged the post. A moderator should be looking at this soon.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could take the average of all of the star rating of his posts. This would also mean that privileges will need new ways of being given, since a person with one post that has a 4-star rating shouldn't have the same privileges as a person with 200 posts with an average of 4 stars.
2. You could simply convert ranges of reputation to stars. People with under 500 could have 1 star. People under 1000 have two. 2000->3, 4000->4, 8000->5.
3. A combination of the above